# Linear transformation of polynomials in Abstract Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

A friend of mine and I are studying for our abstract algebra test and we have no idea how to solve this question:

Is this a valid linear transformation?
$$
F: P_n(\mathbb{R}) \to P_n(\mathbb{R}); \, \, F\left(p(x)\right) = p'(x) + x^2p''(x)
$$

We know that we must prove $F(u+v)=F(u)+F(v)$ and $F(\alpha u) = \alpha F(u)$. I'd greatly appreciate any idea or tip.

Comment: A fundamental difficulty many students seem to have at this point in their learning is to appreciate that here $p$ is the variable of $F$. So check whether $F(p+q)=F(p)+F(q)$ and $F(ap)=aF(p)$. The usual variable $x$ is only the variable of $p$. Its role is very similar to the role of the subscript $i$, when dealing with vectors $(x_i)_{i=1}^n=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Thank you, now I can comprehend it better.

Comment: In fact it would have been much clearer to write $F:p\mapsto p'+x^2p''$; indeed $F$ cannot be applied to values $p(a)$ of the polynomial $p$ at all (and $F(p(x))$ only makes sense through the swindle "if you substitute $x$ for $x$ into $p$, then you get back $p$, so $p(x)=p$").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start on one side and try to get it into the form of the other.

To prove $F(p + q) = F(p) + F(q)$:

$ F(p(x) + q(x)) = (p(x) + q(x))' + x^2(p(x)+q(x))'' $

expanding and rearranging

$ = (p'(x) + x^2p''(x) ) + (q'(x) + x^2q''(x)) = F(p(x)) + F(q(x)) $

try a similar thing for multiplication by a scalar.

Answer (score 4):

You can also prove by smaller bites, verifying that:

1. The mapping $p\mapsto p'$ is linear.
2. The mapping $p\mapsto x\cdot p$ is linear.
3. If $\phi$ and $\psi$ are linear mappings (both $V\to W$ for some vector spaces $V,W$), then $\phi+\psi:=v\mapsto (\phi(v)+\psi(v))$ is linear again.

(For the second summand, apply 1. twice then 2. twice.)